# how can I convert string type of special character into original?

Tags: python, operators, special-characters

I wanted to do maths calculation using asterick (*) but what if it is in string format? how can I convert it to normal?

I tried 4 "*" 5 and first of all, I was not even expecting it to multiply it, as the operator is in string format but it gave me an error.

Comment: Please share the exact input format and the expected output and the code you tried

Comment: You can't convert the '*' to the multiplication operator, but yuo can use the tools in the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

An asterisk in the form of a string variable cannot be converted directly to a mathematical operator; however, it is possible to take the string "*" and use it to perform multiplication by using an if statement.

Let's say you are given some string variable 'operator', and two integer variables 'a' and 'b'. The code would look something like this:

```
if operator == "*":
     product = a * b
     print(product)
```

In your case, you would set the 'a' and 'b' variables to 4 and 5 respectively, meaning the example above would print 20 if the 'operator' variable was "*".

Comment: Oh I get it! I will try this in my code. Thank you.